Electric field generated by an infinite plain sheet as limit of the thickniss $d \to 0$ of an infinite slab
I'm working on an assignment where I need to find the electric field generated by an infinite sheet as the limit of the electric field produced by an infinite slab with uniform charge density $\rho > 0$ and thickness $d$.
From my calculations, the electric field generated by the slab is:
$$
\vec{E}(r) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\rho y}{\varepsilon_0} \hat{y} & \text{if } |y| < d, \\
\frac{\rho d}{\varepsilon_0} \hat{y} & \text{if } |y| > d,
\end{cases}
$$
This result was derived using Gauss’s law with a cylindrical Gaussian surface. My professor gave us the hint that, as $d \to 0$, the total charge of the slab must remain constant, transitioning from the slab to an infinite sheet.
Here’s where I'm encountering some difficulties. To keep the total charge constant, I used the condition $dq = \rho dV = \sigma dS$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density of the infinite sheet. Assuming that the slab and the sheet have the same surface area, $A = ab$, I found:
$$
q = \int dq = \int \rho dV = \int \sigma dS \implies \rho abd = \sigma ab \implies \sigma = \rho d.
$$
Therefore, $\rho d$ must be treated as a constant. In the limit as $d \to 0$ and for $|y| > d$, I recover the electric field of the infinite sheet:
$$
\vec{E}(r) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0},
$$
as expected. However, I'm unsure if this reasoning is fully correct, or if I’ve made any mistakes in my approach. Could you help me spot any errors?

I think you show the right reasoning, although it may not be presented in the most intuitive way. Here is what might be a slightly clearer reformulation (but it's neither better nor worse than your version).
By definition, $\rho$ is the volumic charge in the slab, that is:
$$\rho = \frac{Q}{V} = \frac{Q}{Ad},$$
where $Q$ is the total charge in the slab; $V$, $A$, and $d$ are respectively the volume, surface area and thickness of the slab.
Now in the case of a vanishing thickness ($d\rightarrow 0$), only the $|y|>d$ part of your slab result will apply. (We are never inside the 2D sheet.) Replacing $\rho$ by the above expression and considering that $\sigma = \frac{Q}{A}$ by definition immediately gives you the expression you are looking for:
$$\frac{\rho d}{\epsilon_0} = \frac{\frac{Qd}{Ad}}{\epsilon_0} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}.$$
This is mostly just a slightly different way to phrase your idea. Your reasoning is correct.
